# Error using e.g. \usepackage[english,german]{babel} instead of \usepackage[german,english]{babel}

Tags: babel

Using

```
\usepackage[english,german]{babel}
```

-> ERROR

or

```
\usepackage[german]{babel}
```

-> ERROR

rather then

```
\usepackage[german,english]{babel}
```

-> COMPILES

Produces an error. Why?

Extended example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\setlength{\headheight}{1.1\baselineskip}
\usepackage[english,german]{babel}
\usepackage[german]{datenumber}
\usepackage{scrpage2} \pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{totpages}
\clearscrheadfoot 
\ifoot{\selectlanguage{german}\today}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `german` is outdated. Use `ngerman`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Should it cause an error, though?

Comment: @cfr: I don't know. The fragments by the user do not reveal much.

Comment: Welcome! It will be hard to help you very effectively without more information. (Unless the switch to `ngerman` just works.) We have no context in the form of an example we can compile to reproduce the error. We don't even know what the error is. And why is this tagged `r` and `sweave`? Are they required to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Which error does it produce? Can you please make a minimal example (a file as short as possible!) that allows us to reproduce the error and edit it into aour question?

Comment: @cfr I removed those tags. They can be added again if necessary…

Comment: 1 - ngerman produces the same. 2 - yes R Sweave is needed. Maybe this problem occurs only with R Sweave. [english,german] would be nice if it wil work otherwise \selectlanguage{german} has to be used.

Comment: @b4154 if you want to notify either one of us in a comment you need to type @ followed by the user name. We still need to see a minimal example if we want to help you

Comment: @clemens and others, example e.g.: \ifoot{\selectlanguage{german}\today}

Comment: @b4154 that is *not* a minimal example. By that I mean a complete document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that we can copy, compile so we get the *same* error!

Comment: Sample you can see above in the question now:

Comment: @b4154 your example gives `! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \SweaveOpts` (independent from `babel`). It does produce the error you have in your original file!

Comment: @clemens: And do you know what the problem is! I do not understand really your comment. \SweaveOpts is to use Sweave

Comment: @b4154 I copied your extended example, ran pdflatex on it and that is the error I got. Please confirm this for yourself! Do you understand what a minimal working example is?

Comment: @b4154 Please read [the information here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?s=1|1.3417) for help creating a Minimal (non-)Working Example. Right now, attempting to compile your example will give the error clemens has reported. We need an example which we can copy-paste-compile ***to reproduce the error you need help with***. Please also tell us which error that is so that we can make sure we are reproducing the problem and not something else. My guess would be the active character mentioned in Ultrike Fischer's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well my crystal ball guesses that you have a problem with quote signs. In german there are active and used for accents. Compare

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
"abc
\end{document}
```

[image]

with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
"abc
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your R code contains quote signs, they can break if they are active. You can use `\shorthandoff` to locally disable the "feature":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}  
"abc

\shorthandoff{"}
"abc

\shorthandon{"}
"abc
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is not my problem but explain what you can do with the package

Comment: Well did you try out what happen if you add `\shorthandoff{"}` before the `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}` in your example?

Comment: Using \shorthandoff{"} before the \SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE} solves the problem. Now I can use \usepackage[english,german]{babel}. Why?

Comment: Maybe the problem came beacause I used german ä. ö, and ü directly. So the error came. With \shorthandoff{"} directly using ä. ö, and ü  makes no problems instead of using "a, "o, and "u. Am I right?

Comment: I don't have R and knitr or sweave or whatever you are using to process the R code and I can't test what they are injecting in the latex document, so I'm only guessing: I don't think that ä, ö, ü is a problem but you should load `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (assuming your file is in utf8). And you should always put `\shorthandoff{"}` *before* every chunk of R code, and  `\shorthandon{"}` *after*  every piece of R code.